# How find this sequence recursive relations

Tags: sequences-and-series

**Question:**

> Let $$A_{n}=\sum_{i=0}^{n-3}(-1)^{n+i-2}\dfrac{13n^2-31n-10ni+9i+i^2+16}{(3n-i-3)(3n-i-4)(2n-i-3)!\cdot i!}$$

I want find the $A_{n}$ recursive relations,such as following form
$$A_{n}=B_{n}+C_{n}A_{n-1}+D_{n}A_{n-2}+\cdots$$
I have try sometimes,and can't find it,can you help me?
Thank you

PS,This my boss give me a question.I guess his also can't.because he always give some question to me( his can't solve it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note:* In the following I provide a *simplification* of the expression for $A_{n}$. So a recurrence relation should be easier derivable from that. Up to now I couldn't find any. But, maybe the reader has a clever idea or the proper tooling to derive it from these simpler expressions.

We show:

> The following is valid for $n \geq 4$:
>
> \begin{align*}
> A_n&=\sum_{i=0}^{n-3}(-1)^{n+i}\frac{13n^2-31n-10ni+9i+i^2+16}
> {(3n-i-3)(3n-i-4)(2n-i-3)!i!}\\
> &=\frac{2}{(2n-3)!}\left((-1)^n\frac{(n-2)^2}{3(n-1)}-\binom{2n-4}{n-1}\right.\tag{1}\\
> &\qquad\qquad+\sum_{i=1}^{n-3}(-1)^i\binom{2n-2}{n+i}\frac{i^2}{2n+i-1}\tag{2}\\
> &\qquad\qquad\left.+\sum_{i=1}^{n-3}(-1)^i\binom{2n-3}{n+i}\frac{i}{2n+i-1}\right)\tag{3}\\
> \end{align*}

So, a recurrence relation for $A_n$ could be searched by *separately analysing* (1), (2) and (3). The terms from (1) will seemingly contribute rational functions in $n$ and shouldn't be too hard to find.

> The challenge is to find recurrence relations for 
>   \begin{align*}
> B_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n-3}(-1)^i\binom{2n-2}{n+i}\frac{i^2}{2n+i-1}\qquad n\geq 4
> \end{align*}
>   and
>   \begin{align*}
> C_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n-3}(-1)^i\binom{2n-3}{n+i}\frac{i}{2n+i-1}\qquad n\geq 4
> \end{align*}

Nevertheless it seems that finding a recurrence relation for $B_n$ and $C_n$ should be more feasible than finding one for $A_n$.

---

Let's proof the above statement:

> The first step is to change the index from $i \rightarrow n-3-i $ (4) and introduce binomial coefficients to make the representation more convenient (5).
>
> \begin{align*}
> A_n&=\sum_{i=0}^{n-3}(-1)^{n+i}\frac{13n^2-31n-10ni+9i+i^2+16}
> {(3n-i-3)(3n-i-4)(2n-i-3)!i!}\\
> &=\sum_{i=0}^{n-3}(-1)^{i+1}\frac{4n^2+2n+8ni+i^2-3i-2}
> {(2n+i)(2n-1+i)(n+i)!(n-i-3)!}\tag{4}\\
> &=\frac{1}{(2n-3)!}\sum_{i=0}^{n-3}(-1)^{i+1}\binom{2n-3}{n+i}\frac{4n^2+2n+8ni+i^2-3i-2}
> {(2n+i)(2n-1+i)}\tag{5}\\
> \end{align*}

Next we apply partial fraction decomposition:
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{(2n+i)(2n+i-1)}&=\frac{1}{2n+i-1}-\frac{1}{2n+i}\\
\frac{4n^2+2n+8ni+i^2-3i-2}{2n+i-1}&=2n+3i+2-2\frac{i(i+1)}{2n+i-1}\\
\frac{4n^2+2n+8ni+i^2-3i-2}{2n+i}&=2n+3i+1-2\frac{(i+1)^2}{2n+i-1}\\
\end{align*}
And so we get
\begin{align*}
\frac{4n^2+2n+8ni+i^2-3i-2}{(2n+i)(2n+i-1)}=1-2\frac{i(i+1)}{2n+i-1}+2\frac{(i+1)^2}{2n+i}
\end{align*}

> We can now write $A_n$ as
>   \begin{align*}
> A_n&=\frac{1}{(2n-3)!}\sum_{i=0}^{n-3}(-1)^{i+1}\binom{2n-3}{n+i}\tag{5}\\
> &\qquad\qquad-\frac{2}{(2n-3)!}\sum_{i=1}^{n-3}(-1)^{i+1}\binom{2n-3}{n+i}\frac{i(i+1)}{2n+i-1}\tag{6}\\
> &\qquad\qquad+\frac{2}{(2n-3)!}\sum_{i=0}^{n-3}(-1)^{i+1}\binom{2n-3}{n+i}\frac{(i+1)^2}{2n+i}\tag{7}\\
> \end{align*}

Note, that the sum in (6) does nothing contribute to $A_n$ if $i=0$, so we start the index with $i=1$.
We can simplify (5) by considering it as telescoping sum:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=0}^{n-3}&(-1)^{i+1}\binom{2n-3}{n+i}\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{n-3}(-1)^{i+1}\binom{2n-4}{n+i-1}+\sum_{i=0}^{n-3}(-1)^{i+1}\binom{2n-4}{n+i}\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{n-3}(-1)^{i+1}\binom{2n-4}{n+i-1}-\sum_{i=1}^{n-2}(-1)^{i+1}\binom{2n-4}{n+i-1}\\
&=-\binom{2n-4}{n-1}
\end{align*}

> Therefore $A_n$ can be written as:
>   \begin{align*}
> A_n&=\frac{-1}{(2n-3)!}\binom{2n-4}{n-1}\\
> &\qquad\qquad+\frac{2}{(2n-3)}\sum_{i=1}^{n-3}(-1)^{i}\binom{2n-3}{n+i}\frac{i(i+1)}{2n+i-1}\tag{8}\\
> &\qquad\qquad+\frac{2}{(2n-3)}\sum_{i=1}^{n-2}(-1)^{i}\binom{2n-3}{n+i-1}\frac{i^2}{2n+i-1}\tag{9}
> \end{align*}
>   Observe the index shift $i\rightarrow i+1$ in (9) to get the same denominator as in (8).

Now we *separate the last summand* with $i=n-2$ in (9). In doing so the index range in (8) and (9) is $1\leq i \leq n-3$ and we can collect the summands with $i^2$.

> \begin{align*}
> A_n&=\frac{-1}{(2n-3)!}\binom{2n-4}{n-1}\\
> &\qquad+\frac{2}{(2n-3)!}\sum_{i=1}^{n-3}(-1)^{i}
> \left(\binom{2n-3}{n+i}+\binom{2n-3}{n+i-1}\right)\frac{i^2}{2n+i-1}\tag{10}\\
> &\qquad+\frac{2}{(2n-3)!}\sum_{i=1}^{n-3}(-1)^{i}
> \binom{2n-3}{n+i}\frac{i}{2n+i-1}\\
> &\qquad+\frac{2}{(2n-3)!}(-1)^{n-2}\binom{2n-3}{2n-3}\frac{(n-2)^2}{3n-3}
> \end{align*}

Observing that in (10)
\begin{align*}
\binom{2n-3}{n+i}+\binom{2n-3}{n+i-1}=\binom{2n-2}{n+i}
\end{align*}
and collecting the first and last summand results in

> \begin{align*}
> A_n&=\frac{2}{(2n-3)!}\left((-1)^n\frac{(n-2)^2}{3(n-1)}-\binom{2n-4}{n-1}\right.\\
> &\qquad\qquad+\sum_{i=1}^{n-3}(-1)^i\binom{2n-2}{n+i}\frac{i^2}{2n+i-1}\\
> &\qquad\qquad\left.+\sum_{i=1}^{n-3}(-1)^i\binom{2n-3}{n+i}\frac{i}{2n+i-1}\right)\\
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim follows.

Comment: Oh,Nice works.+1

Comment: In mathoverflow @ Michael Stoll give a ugly recurrence relation ,see:http://mathoverflow.net/questions/191161/this-sequence-a-n-have-recursive-relations,  and I think you some reslut is important to me,Thank you

Comment: @math110: Thanks, you're welcome. Maybe you could ask MichaelStoll from MO if he might also find a (hopefully simpler) recurrence relation for $B_n$ and $C_n$. Best regards,

Comment: @math110: Hi, math110! Thanks a lot for accepting my answer and granting the bounty! Best regards,